# Travelling Salesman - approximation online software?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, heuristics, np, np-hard

would any of you know of a solution to generate even a mediocre solution to the travelling salesman problem. I have 3 people meant to visit 31 destinations... I'm not sure how to approach that?

Thanks to all -

Maxim

Comment: What have you researched thus far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could try a greedy approach by picking an arbitrary point to start (if a starting point is not specified) and then on each step you travel to the closest point to your current point. Assuming that distance between points can be calculated in constant time you can then find a path in O(n^2) time.

To clarify, the following pseudo code should help (I haven't written this kind of thing in a while, so I hope this is clear enough)

```
Name: GreedyPath(C, p)
Input: C - a non-empty collection of points to visit
       p - a starting point in C
Output: S - a sequence of points covering C
Algorithm:
  Remove p from C
  If C is empty
    Return the sequence containing only p
  Else
    Let p1 be the closest point to p in C
    Let S = GreedyPath(C, p1)
    Append p to the start of S
    Return S
```

Obviously the time consuming part is finding the closest point to `p` every time, but for `n` points this should only require `n(n-1)/2` distance calculations (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: I would speculate that this should give good results if the points are fairly evenly spaced.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options including: [Nearest Neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm), [Christofides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm), and [Lin–Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin%E2%80%93Kernighan_heuristic).

If these fail, you can always use [code](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/index.html) from the experts (free for academic researchers).

Comment: Even though posting only links is frowned upon on SO, your answer is clearly better than mine. Thank you, I have learned from it.